# Do humans normally pass gas 6 to 21 times per day?

Tags: biology, physiology

[10 Fascinating Facts About Farting](http://www.oddee.com/item_98612.aspx)

> People Pass Gas About 14 Times Per Day

[Fart, Burp, and Embrace Gas!](http://wondergressive.com/gas-in-the-body-2/)

> Catapulting gaseous elements out of your orifices 13 to 21 times a day is average. Farting and burping even 30 times a day is, unfortunately for us, still a normal occurrence.

[Gas, Bloating, and Burping - Topic Overview](http://www.webmd.com/heartburn-gerd/tc/gas-bloating-and-burping-topic-overview)

> Burping 3 or 4 times after eating a meal is normal and is usually caused by swallowing air.
>
> All people pass gas, but some people produce more gas than others. It is normal to pass gas from 6 to 20 times a day. Although this may embarrass or annoy you, excess intestinal gas usually is not caused by a serious health condition.

Are these estimates accurate?

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question. Doesn't disgust me in the slightest. Not sure how exciting it is, but bodily functions happen and the OP has some notable claims so it is on topic.

Comment: OP lives an amazing life if he is skeptical about this.

Answer (score 7):

From [Evaluation of an extremely flatulent patient: Case report and proposed diagnostic and therapeutic approach](http://www.nature.com/ajg/journal/v93/n11/full/ajg1998522a.html)

> A study involving 25 healthy subjects ingesting their ad libitum diets indicated that gas was passed an average of 10 times/day with an upper limit of normal (mean plusminus 2 SD) of 20 times/day

This was linked to [The relation of passage of gas an abdominal bloating to colonic gas production.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8554251) as the primary source.  On a study of 25 participants:

> Participants passed gas 10 +/- 5.0 times per day (mean +/- SD) during the placebo period

In [Investigation of normal flatus production in healthy volunteers](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1378885/pdf/gut00587-0087.pdf), they reported a median of 8 events over a 24 hour period.

Comment: The OP has already quoted a number of secondary sources (including WebMD). To address the question (rather than just repeat the claims), we need to raise the quality of the evidence above secondary sources and appeals to authority, to actual peer-reviewed experimental results (or surveys of such results).

Comment: I rewrote my answer to link to a couple of journal studies.   Sorry about the original answer, I'm still feeling my way around this site.